# Find records between two dates not working when type is timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have one table which having `dates` and I want to find date between two dates.

For `created_date` table field, I have used `timestamp` type. Now I have created following sql query to find records between to dates like `2015-04-15 to 2015-04-21`.

### My Table

```
id  created_date
**  *******************
10  2015-04-15 10:49:26
13  2015-04-17 09:49:06
14  2015-04-21 14:59:42
15  2015-05-20 14:26:07
16  2015-06-11 13:25:34
```

### My Select Query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE created_date
BETWEEN '2015-04-15'
AND '2015-04-21'
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

As I am using `timestamp` type from above table, sql is not working becouse I am comparing with this data formate `YYYY-MM-DD`. I want to get records with using `timestamp` type and dont want to change from table but fetch results without reading `HH:MM:SS`.

For example, If I search with this two dates: `2015-04-15 to 2015-04-21`

I want this records:

```
id  created_date
**  *******************
10  2015-04-15 10:49:26
13  2015-04-17 09:49:06
14  2015-04-21 14:59:42
```

Any Idea how to get records like this :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQl `DATE()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE(created_date)
BETWEEN '2015-04-15'
AND '2015-04-21'
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your query like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE created_date
BETWEEN '2015-04-15 00:00:00'//add 00:00:00
AND '2015-04-21 23:59:59'// add  23:59:59
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: I am getting records but is it right way to pass `00:00:00 to 23:59:59` after dates?

Comment: Any other solution to not consider `HH:MM:SS` in select query?

Comment: date `2015-04-21` means all record below 2015-04-21 00:00:00 . If your date is `2015-04-21:00:01:23` this record not selected in you query. so we need to add `23:59:59` to get all record of that day

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ?  For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE created_date
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-15 00:00:00')
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-21 23:59:59')
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE created_date
>= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-15 00:00:00')
AND created_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-21 23:59:59')
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

*The above is just an example.*

It is ideal to use the type of DATETIME for more optimisation, and it's so much easier for querying.  I'd really look into doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE created_date
BETWEEN '2015-04-15 00:00:00'
AND '2015-04-21 23:59:59'
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```